# Show that a bi-partition number of edges, |{st ∈ E|s ∈ S, t ∈ T}| ≥ |E|/4

Tags: graph-theory

I have this exercise: 
Given an oriented graph G = (V, E), with at least 2 vertices, prove that you can build in polynomial time a bi-partition (S, T) (S ∪ T = V, S ∩ T = ∅, S, T != ∅) so that 
|{st ∈ E|s ∈ S, t ∈ T}| ≥ |E|/4.

Any suggestions are welcome. thank you.

Comment: Are you learning about probabilistic methods?

Comment: No, we haven't got that far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple one is the following:

1. Start with an arbitrary bipartition $X,Y$.
2. Let $H$ be the subgraph of $G$ belonging to this bipartition,
   i.e. $e=xy\in E(H)$ if and only if $x\in X, y\in Y,e\in G$.
3. Iterate over all vertices to find a vertex $v$ whose $G$-degree is larger than twice its $H$-degree.
   If you find nothing you are done.
   This step takes at most $n$ iterations, and each of them can be done in polynomial time.
4. Now move $v$ to the other partition and go back to step 2 with this new bipartition.

Every time you go back to step 2 the number of edges in $H$ has increased,
so you loop at most ${n\choose 2}$ times, which guarantees that the algorithm stops
and is polynomial.

I leave it to you to prove that the final bipartition satisfies your requirement.

Comment: Beautiful. The only thing that comes to my head is Handshaking Lemma. Is it enough if I prove ≥ |E|/2? It's pretty obvious that ≥ |E|/4 after that, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed this algorithm does more than you asked for :)